# Want in return an integer value after time delta operation

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I am creating a column in pandas which calculates difference between two dates. The result value I am expecting is an integer but the operation returns values with a suffix 'days' with the integer. How I can eliminate the suffix?

```
data\['TIMESTAMP'\] = pd.to_datetime(data\['TIMESTAMP'\],format='%d-%b-%Y')
data\['EXPIRY_DT'\] = pd.to_datetime(data\['EXPIRY_DT'\],format='%d-%b-%Y')
data.sort_values(by = \['TIMESTAMP','SYMBOL','EXPIRY_DT'\],inplace=True)
data.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
data\['DTE'\] = data\['EXPIRY_DT'\] - data\['TIMESTAMP'\]
data['DTE'].head()
```

```
0   6 days
1   6 days
2   6 days
3   6 days
4   6 days
Name: DTE, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

I am looking to get '6' instead of '6 days'

Comment: `data['DTE'].dt.days`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```py
data['DTE'] = (data['EXPIRY_DT'] - data['TIMESTAMP']).dt.days
```